# google_maps_flutter does not work correctly on Android 11

Tags: flutter, google-maps, android-11, flutter-packages, google-maps-flutter

I am using the **google_maps_flutter** package and whenever I click the button to launch the google map I encounter this error:

> google maps is not installed or is disabled

But such a thing was not true :(((
This error is happened to me in Android 11.

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you will need to add the Google Maps package "com.google.android.apps.maps" as an entry in your AndroidManifest.xml entry:

```
<manifest package="com.your.package">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: just add this line inside the root element of your AndroidMainfest.xml file

<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
  </queries>